# VBA - UserForm insert register between two lines

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm making an Excel spreadsheet in order to do Project's cost control. I am using UserForms to insert each cost in a specific cell inside the worksheet.

These costs are subdivided into "Modules", and each module has its own UserForm so that you're able to insert the cost inside the refered module.

Below are pictures of the Modules worksheet and also of the UserForm that each module has (+ Button).

[image: Modules Worksheet, + Button opens the UserForm]

[image: UserForm (opened by the + Button]

I am not being able to insert each cost between two modules, e.g: If I am going to insert a cost in the first module, the cost needs to be inserted in a line between modules 1 and 2.

Since I do not have much knowledge in VBA programming, it would be very much appreciated if I could get some help. What's the code for the UserForm to insert a register (UserForm answer) between two existent and filled lines?

If I was not too clear about my request, feel free to question me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! That's a rather *broad* thing to ask on this site. Are you stuck on a particular step of the process? What's your code-behind like for the form, which specific part isn't working, and how? Please [edit] your question to narrow it down to a specific issue.

Comment: Hello, Mathieu! Thanks for answering. So in a previous version of this worksheet, I was using the userform to insert in a random empty cell. Now, I need the userform to insert a new line between the two (+) signs, and I dont know how to do that. Each one of the (+) is a different userform (they all equal, and have the same information). Basically I do not know how to code for the userform to insert a new line between two other lines and then insert its results in that line.